# How to import to multi-record set custom fields

Tags: import

I am trying to import records to a custom multi-record set of fields.
I read somewhere that it was a new feature for 4.5.8 but now for the life of me I cannot find where I read it - pretty sure it was the release notes, but may have got the version wrong.

Would appreciate a pointer in the right direction. (we are currently on 4.6.4)

Many thanks

Comment: Note this the import relates to multi-record sets attached to a contact record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps:

1. Contacts > Import Contacts
2. Click the help ? at the end of: "The Import Wizard.... them here."
3. Click the link on here at the end of: "If you need to import Multi-value Custom Data for contacts.... from here: /civicrm/import/custom?reset=1 .

You should see the multi-record field to import

Comment: May be helpful to include this link in your answer so people can get to it more easily ie /civicrm/import/custom?reset=1

Comment: Thanks so much Sanjay... I would never have found it!   
Agree with petednz - the link to multi record import needs to be much more obvious on Civi itself

Comment: can anybody in this thread help me with this question? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19107/help-needed-in-importing-multi-value-custom-fields

Comment: I can't get this to work for dates :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can import multi-value custom fields through the API, including the [API CSV Import GUI](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui).  You use the `CustomValue` API; you can also use [the command-line CSV import tool](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/4723/12) or even `drush`.

Your contact ID field should be imported as `entity_id`.  If the custom field ID is "4", then import to `custom_4`.

As an example - if your field set is called "schools attended", with custom fields "school"  (custom field ID 7) and "degree" (custom field ID 8) for a contact with an ID of 123, your data may look like this:

```
entity_id | custom_7                 | custom_8
123       | University of Wisconsin  | BA
123       | Rutgers University       | MA
```

Comment: Trying this again and not possible via the API CSV Import GUI. The only select options I have are "Entity ID" and "- do not import -" -> I can't map any of my custom_ fields to any custom_ fields. This site is running ESR. I was looking for a UI option (so an admin could do it) but going command line now :-)

Comment: Hmm - in API Explorer you can select "Other" instead of "Do Not Import".  So much for my confidently incorrect answer :)

Comment: I don’t get an Other option in API CSV import -> I ended up writing a little drush script - will post that here for completeness 

Answer (score 1):

If you have complicated import needs - for instance, you need to import multi-value custom fields as part of a larger import - you may want to consider the "Advanced Import-Form Processor" approach.

I really need to write docs up, but in general:

- Install [Form Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor).
- Create a new form processor instance.  Each "input" should correspond to a column in your source data.
- When creating your actions, the "Update Individual" action won't import multi-value custom fields - but the "Contact: Update Custom Data" action will.
- Test it out using the "Try Out" functionality to ensure it works as expected.
  Now the magic bit - how to use this as an import instead of for form submissions?
- Install [Advanced Import](https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-import).
- Install [Advanced Import Form Processor](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/advimportformprocessor).

Advanced Import gives you an import UI; Advanced Import Form Processor lets you use a Form Processor instance to process each line in your file.  Advanced Import has some limitations (e.g. it doesn't handle large files well) and Form Processor is relatively slow - but you can create pretty much any import you need without coding by using these three extensions together.  *And* it has an end-user focused UI.  Much like Views or Webform, an admin can create something complex, but the end result is usable by end users.

Below is a screenshot of a Form Processor instance I created.  I was given a list of students with their schools and related information.  I was able to:

- Create students if they didn't exist, or use existing contacts if they did ([XCM](https://docs.civicrm.org/xcm/en/latest/) integrates with Form Processor for very fine-grained duplicate matching).
- Create the school if necessary.
- Create a "Student/School" relationship that filled in relationship custom fields "Major" and "Degree".  Note that you can import relationships with standard import, but can NOT import to relationship custom fields.
- Imported alumni information, which is stored in a multi-record custom field group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a drush script to import data into custom multi record fields:

create file `import-script.scr`
run it as: `drush scr import-script.scr`

script:

```
<?php

$file = '/var/www/html/sites/default/scripts/civicrm_value_import.csv';

$fh = fopen($file, 'r');

while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {

  $contact_id = $row[8];
  if (empty($contact_id)) {
     continue;
  }

  // Build array for new data
  $import = [
    'entity_id' => $contact_id,
    'discharge_reason_329' => $row[14],
    'primary_presenting_problem_335' => $row[15],
    'principal_diagnosis_336' => $row[16],
    'diagnosis_2_337' => $row[17],
    'diagnosis_3_338' => $row[18],
    'opioid_dependency_339' => $row[19]
  ];
  if (!empty($row[11])) {
    $import += ['referral_date_331' => $row[11]];
  }
  if (!empty($row[12])) {
    $import += ['enrolment_date_332' => $row[12]];
  }
  if (!empty($row[13])) {
    $import += ['discharge_date_333' => $row[13]];
  }         
  if (!empty($row[21])) {
    $import += ['initiation_date_341' => $row[21]];
  }
  
  //  print_r([$import]);

  // Insert
  db_insert('civicrm_value_raam_66')
    ->fields($import)
    ->execute();

  // For testing one row
  // break;

}
```