# 404 Error: Not found while Importing Contacts

Tags: import

I'm migrating from one host service to another. We've installed the newest version of CiviCRM on the new host, DreamHost. I'm exporting contacts from the old CiviCRM database and importing them into the new CiviCRM database. It worked fine for 154 records and 233 records, but I'm getting a 404 Error when importing 713 records. DreamHost tried to increase the PHP limits, but it didn't help. I could try breaking the imports into smaller chunks, but I've got 11,000 records! I found a similar problem in the StackExchange, https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29865.msg127907#msg127907 but it went unanswered. Can someone help me? Thanks, in advance! Jim

Comment: You can try to import through the command line.  See http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/how-do-i-import-contacts-through-the-command-line

Comment: I tried using the command line and got it to work, but unsatisfactorily. I have lots of fields of data, but the only data that gets imported is the name and email address?!? Another problem. I really only wanted to update a couple of fields that didn't import properly the first time. It doesn't look like this method can handle that. I ended up with duplicate records, and the new record was hardly populated, as I mentioned. Is there a way I can stop the CiviCRM import from timing out after 3 minutes with the 404 error?? Thanks...jim

Comment: BTW, I still need to find out why the command line approach isn't working, for future imports. Any ideas? All the column headings come from a civicrm export from version 4.4 and the import is into 4.6.6. I made all the column headings lower case, and replaced spaces with underscore (_). The email address is kinda near the end of the string and that's working, so I'd think other fields would too?!?