# Command line import error message

Tags: import, cli

I'm using the command line import, following info provided here:

[How do I import contacts through the command line?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/how-do-i-import-contacts-through-the-command-line)

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34033.0

But getting the following error message:  Invalid file format for filepath/filename.csv. It must be a valid csv with separator ',' or ';'

My file is a valide csv, downloaded using Google Docs to csv, which has been an acceptable way to create clean csv files.  Not sure why the import.php won't accept this file.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  My csv file was on a staging server that required a user name and password for access.  The error message was misleading, nothing wrong with the csv file.  Once I put the file on the server in a place that is not password protected, it worked fine.