# Can I specify a dedupe rule and import type (e.g. update) when using command line import

Tags: import, cli

I'm using the command line import, following info provided here:

[How do I import contacts through the command line?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/how-do-i-import-contacts-through-the-command-line)

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34033.0

Since I have data that includes address, relationships and membership, I assume I'll have to import in stages.  How do I specify a dedupe (based on email address) command and do updates using the command line?

Answer (score 3):

The command line import uses the default unsupervised rule for deducing.  Out of the box that's just email.

When using command line import if the unsupervised dedupe rule says the import line is a duplicate then it will do an update instead of a creating new record.