# cron setup failing in new Wordpress installaion

Tags: wordpress, cron, cli

New installation of 4.7.14 into a WordPress 4.7 site located in a subdomain (e.g. sub.domain.com) hosted at A2. Everything good except for the "Cron Not Running". Created a new WP user with admin privileges, but still get "ERROR: Invalid username and/or password". Happens when trying to run from the command line as well.

php /home/me/public_html/sub.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s sub.domain.com -u WP-user -p WP-password -e Job -a execute

What am I missing?

Comment: Progress! Using full path of `/usr/bin/php` got the error `cli.php can only be run from command line.` Using the hack at [link](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/how-do-i-import-contacts-through-the-command-line/4724#4724) I now get a bunch of html and then `<!-- W3 Total Cache: Minify debug info:
Engine:             disk
Theme:              2fa4e
Template:           index
-->
/continued in next comment

Comment: (final output)
<!-- W3 Total Cache: Page cache debug info:
Engine:             disk: enhanced
Cache key:          gs.joewhite.com/_index.html
Caching:            enabled
Creation Time:      0.005s
Header info:
X-Powered-By:        PHP/5.5.38
Last-Modified:       Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Expires:             Fri, 16 Dec 2016 04:08:18 GMT
Pragma:              public
Cache-Control:       max-age=3600, public
Etag:                64a26f9af5e9eb7cc1fa0a8df39c39cc
-->
Cron now running every 15 minutes, but still getting no cron runs have been recorded.

Comment: Are you using the WP user nickname or email address?  I set one of these up recently on WP and could only get it to work correctly with the email address of the cronuser, not the nickname/username.

Comment: I finally just wiped and reinstalled from scratch. Worked with the WP username:

/path/to/php /home/me/public_html/sub.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php  -u username -p password -s sub.domain.com -e Job -a execute

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this but it sounds like a permissions problem and you may need to update the permissions in root/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php to be executable. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, peterb. I had forgotten to fix those permissions when I reinstalled, but even with it set to 755 I still get

ERROR: Invalid username and/or password

when using the WP username; when using the same user's full email address, I still get

Failed to login as [useremail]

Comment: Would it be worth trying to move public_html after sub.domain.com in your cron command?

Comment: Thanks again, peterb, but `/home/me/public_html/sub.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php` is the actual path.