# How do I use import and export php classes with aegir?

Tags: import, civicrm.settings.php, core, multisite, drupal-multi-site

How do I use export.php and import.php to work with multiple sites run with Aegir.

All of them share the same files (php classes) and when I specify the site with -s mysite.org I get nothing (literally the command executes without error it just doesn't output anything).

When I run without spcifying mysite

```
php export.php -e Contact
```

> PHP Warning: 
>   include_once(/var/aegir/platforms/beta/sites/all/modules/civicrm/../../../default/civicrm.settings.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/aegir/platforms/beta/sites/all/modules/civicrm/civicrm.config.php
>   on line 118 PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/var/aegir/platforms/beta/sites/all/modules/civicrm/../../../default/civicrm.settings.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/aegir/platforms/beta/sites/all/modules/civicrm/civicrm.config.php
>   on line 118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally made it work was this:

First I needed to set the `CIVICRM_SETTINGS` env variable to the civicrm.settings.php file for my subsite

```
 export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=/var/aegir/platforms/example/sites/my.site.org/civicrm.settings.php
```

Only then could I execute the php file export.php, not with src but with php-script

```
drush php-script  /var/aegir/platforms/example/sites/all/civicrm/bin/csv/export.php -e Contact
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute a PHP script in the context of a selected site, use `drush php-script` or `drush scr`.

In your question you specified the site using `-s example.org`, and I suspect you may be looking for `-l` (`--uri`) rather than `-s` (`--simulate`) to determine which site to load. See the first section of `drush help` output for these flags.

If `-l` doesn't do it, you can also use aliases which Aegir automatically creates for each site - you should find that `drush @example.org vget site_name` works and returns the name of the expected site, because there will be alias files in eg `/var/aegir/.drush/EXAMPLE.ORG.alias.drushrc.php` for each site.

So, you probably want something like: `drush -l example.org scr /path/to/export.php`

- If `drush vget site_name` returns the name of the expected site, you've confirmed Drush can connect to Drupal.
- If `drush cvapi Contact.get` returns contacts from your site, you've confirmed that CiviCRM works when called via Drush.
- If `drush scr import.php` or `drush scr export.php` still don't work, that sounds like those scripts don't bootstrap "normally" for CiviCRM and there may be work to do to get them to behave.

I don't actually know how `import.php`/`export.php` are expected to behave - so I might have led you astray. Looking at them, I'd expect `export.php` probably works via Drush, but I see `import.php` is looking for `$_GET['file']` which Id' expect to require special treatment for Drush use (but I see [this SE answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/how-do-i-import-contacts-through-the-command-line) says it works using `--file=blah.csv`, and that you should call them via `php import.php` not `drush`).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error. Alias works (drush @mysite.org help works) but I still get Could not load the settings file at: /var/aegir/platforms/beta/sites/all/modules/civicrm/../../../default/civicrm.settings.php. I guess it's still targeting the wrong civicrm.settings.php (the default one instead of mysite specific

Comment: Good point - `drush help` works whether or not you have a valid site. I've updated my answer to recommend `drush vget site_name` which will confirm that Drush executes *and* connects to the site you expect.

Comment: Yeah, drush works, and it identifies the proper site_name, but I can't execute the export script. I always get that same error.