# Cannot find import in menu

Tags: import

I am running 4.7.8 but cannot find the option to Import from CSV for multiple choice options under a custom field - is this possible?.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: It's best not to change the question so much in an edit.  Better to ask a second question.  It benefits others to see each question independently.

Answer (score 3):

For the updated question of how to import custom field multiple choice fields, see [How to import to multi-record set custom fields](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3957/105)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're importing.  You can find 'Import Contacts' and 'Import Activities' in the Contacts menu.  'Import Contributions' is found in the Contributions menu.  'Important Participants' in the Events menu.

You can specify the terms of your import on those screens.

[image: Screen shot for import location in menu]

See [Importing Data into CiviCRM](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/importing-data/) and [Importing Data](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Importing+Data) for information on the importing process in Civi.

Comment: You betcha. Make sure to check the answer checkmark if an answer works solves a question for you.