# help needed in importing multi value custom fields

Tags: custom-fields, import, multi-record, data-import

For the below custom fields, suppose a contact has two UG degrees B.Tech, BBA and two PG degrees M.Tech and MBA, I want to add additional set of custom field set, and then add the second degree. Like this I have 100 contacts, How to do through importing .csv file? ...
[image]

When I import I am able to only import the first set of degree, not the second one. I am configuring like the image in the second. However there should be some error in that. Not sure how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but I don't think you can import both the records in a single go. You might need to create two csv file with each value(B.Tech and BBA) of the custom field and import it one by one.

Comment: at first I was skeptical... but It works. thanks