# How to store (and import) historical data (date, integer#1, integer #2, etc.)

Tags: custom-fields, data-import

I want to store data (date, integer #1, integer #2, integer #3) for an organizational contact in CiviCRM. Each month a new record record with the same format will be created for each contact, but with new data.

What is the best way to do that in CiviCRM?

I also want to import that data (historical data from past dates).  Can that be done?

Comment: Have a look at the answer here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/how-to-import-to-multi-record-set-custom-fields

Comment: That might work but I'd probably do it with activities and "regular" custom fields on the activity instead of multicustom, but to answer "best" properly depends on what the daily tasks are that use these fields and what reporting you need.

Comment: Each month a new record would be added (date of data, integer #1, integer #2, integer #3).  The data would be used record and then also to report on the changes (increase or decrease) of the data (integer # 1, integer # 2, integer # 3, etc.) from month to month.  I was thinking of making a report for that, possibly exporting data to a csv for use elsewhere and so that I could create annual totals or averages of the data.

Comment: So then custom fields on activities looks a good option as @demerit says. There are lots of reports for activities both standard ones and those provided by [extensions](https://civicrm.org/extensions?field_extension_civi_use_target_id=96)