# How to import values for Custom Fields configured as "Field Set allow multiple records?"

Tags: import

I think no through regular Contact Import; I can't see how through API CSV Import; if anyone has any other thoughts that would be great.

Seamus told me to try -> `/civicrm/import/custom?reset=1` and that looked promising! -> but trying to import dates I run into an error message that makes no sense -> I got a "value: 2020-01-01 is not of the right field data type: Date" That custom field is configured as a Date field and 2020-01-01 is a date

Do I need to sql my way through this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other date formats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import to multi-record set custom fields](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/how-to-import-to-multi-record-set-custom-fields)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate, but I realize the answer there is incomplete.  I'll add another one now!

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that! You really are like a walking library of all CiviCRM SE questions :-)